# Why are facets not displayed on pages?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I have two entities: **Entity Product** and **Entity Product Category**. **Entity Product** has an entity reference field on the **Entity Product Category**.

##### Goal:

Display categories and their number on the right by facets.

##### What I did:

1. I created the **Product Category** view mode and selected it in **Entity Product**, where I disabled all the fields because I don’t need to display them, because I will display the facets:

[image]

2. Added the necessary fields to the previously created index and once again indexed the **Entity Product**:

[image]

3. Created view Categories results facets which will be used as Facet source. And in **Show:Rendered entity | Settings** in settings selected view mode **Product Category**:

[image]

4. Added a facet:

[image]

5. I chose **Categories results facets** view as Facet source:

[image]

6. Configured the facets:

[image]
[image]

8. Added the **Categories results facets** block to the Block layout:

[image]

But the facets are not displayed on any page.

Answer (score 2):

All of your steps looks fine the only thing i think you are missing is this module https://www.drupal.org/project/core_views_facets
this will allow facets to render in that view after installing this module

go to the view and select Facet serializer that should do the trick hopefully
[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPRYH.png)

Also when you create/register a facet against any view Drupal automatically
creates its block, so for facet to appear on your page the last step you will need to do will be to place the block on your desired sidebar then hopefully facet will be present on that page on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Place the facets inside a context (any theme region you want them) and then aim the context to the page you want the facets.